# How to correctly open new controller from source code?

Tags: ios, swift

Two weeks ago i started my journey with swift and iOS. I have a problem with memory. Initially, after login, my app consumes 30 mb. Then user can choose four windows from menu. I switch between them using this code:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(content[indexPath.row]) as! UINavigationController
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Every time when i choose another option from menu and new window appears, app consumes another 1 mb of memory. After several changes, app consumes 90 mb (checked in xcode instruments). I'm sure that there's something wrong with this code. Should I somehow dismiss old window?

Comment: How do you close previous view controller?

Comment: add more related code in question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using 'presentViewController' you are just modally adding more views to the stack, if the idea is to switch between these 4 views, the TabBarController should be the component to use.

On the other hand, if you just want to change the initial view controller to swap between these views you should change the root view controller by adding the following to the AppDelegate

```
func setRootViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
}
```

And swap between controllers using the following when you need it

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
        appDelegate?.setRootViewController(otherViewController)
```

Hope it helps :)